# How to stop azure dev ops yaml validation build from running for each branch?

Tags: validation, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

We are using azure dev ops for CICD and validating PR's.

Yesterday I decided to start making yaml files for validation builds.

I created the pipeline. I set the branch policy for 'development' fine and the validation build ran okay.

However, something I see is that each time ANY branch gets a change to the files of the directory I've set the validation build for a build triggers.

So, let's say I've made a yaml pipeline(CI only) for project Main(src/Main) and i've set a branch policy on  branch 'development' to trigger a validation build whenever there is a change to that Main folder(src/Main/*) with the Main.sln inside and it has been PR's from branch(i.e. feature/Main/FirstPR). This works, but then if i merge 'development' into any branch which has not had the change to the main directory it will trigger that build. No other branch policy includes validation for Main apart from development even if it has not been PR-ed, but simply pushed to.

Here is an example of the yaml file. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  demands: 
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio
      - vstest

variables:
  solution: 'src/Main/Main.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs: 
    versionSpec: '5.0.0'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '5aaa76ac-3bqa-4567-usd9-btdse1c4c66a'
    restoreDirectory: '../../packages'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set;

```
# A pipeline with no trigger
trigger: none
```

On your validation build pipeline. This will stop the build being run regardless of which branch / paths have been pushed.

The validation build pipeline will still respect the branch policies you've setup for PRs.

You can then have something like;

```
  paths:
    include:
      - 'src/ProjectA/*'
  branches:
    include:
      - development
```

For your CI build pipelines which will trigger when there's a successful PR that affects `ProjectA`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you Adam!