# Multiple pipelines triggered on the same repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have one application repo with two branches called stage and master, I configured 2 pipelines(build, push to ACR and deploy to AKS on different namespaces staging and production respectively in AzureDevops) for each branch.

Now, whenever I commit the code in stage branch, 2 pipelines are generating. one is stage pipeline which needs to execute on the commit. That's fine but master configured pipeline is also executing the stage pipeline. 
Therefore, for every commit two times build is happening (one is by stage and other is by master), therefore two images are push to ACR for the single change and two times deploy is happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop azure dev ops yaml validation build from running for each branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114828/how-to-stop-azure-dev-ops-yaml-validation-build-from-running-for-each-branch)

Answer (score 0):

well, fix your pipeline definition to only trigger on commits to certain branch, since you are not providing your pipeline definition it is configured under triggers (i believe) in visial pipeline editor and under [`triggers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#triggers) in the yaml pipelines

but you should probably promote the images, instead of rebuilding them

Comment: But I configured triggers in both the pipelines like this
 #in master
 branches:
    include:
    - master
    exclude:
    - stage
  paths:
    include:
    - azure-pipelines.yml
    - site/*
    exclude:
    - Dockerfile
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    exclude:
    - stage
  paths:
    include:
    - azure-pipelines.yml
    - site/*
    exclude:
    - Dockerfile

Comment: # in stage-pipeline
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - stage
    exclude:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - azure-pipelines.yml
    - site/*
    exclude:
    - Dockerfile
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - stage
    exclude:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - azure-pipelines.yml
    - site/*
    exclude:
    - Dockerfile

Comment: this is unreadable, edit it into the question and delete these comments